# RegEx if then else for conditional test depending on first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I should allow 2 different input strings formats, with each their own validation.
So eg:

AA2222222222222222

and

2222222222222222

This means that if the first character is a letter, I should validate for ^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{16}$. If the first character is numeric, I should validate for d{16}.

I tried to write it in an conditional regex:

```
^(([a-zA-Z])(?([a-zA-Z])^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{16}$|d{16})
```

but I get a pattern error and can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Any insight would be apreciated

Comment: You can use a single pattern `^(?:[A-Z][A-Z])?\d{16}$` with an optional group. Javscript does not support a conditional syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean this syntax https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to write it in an conditional regex

JavaScript doesn't support [regular expression conditional syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), so `(?ifthen|else)` doesn't work in JavaScript.

> This means that if the first character is a letter, I should validate for ^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{16}$. If the first character is numeric, I should validate for d{16}.

Since the `\d{16}` part is the same, you can just make the `[a-zA-Z]{2}` part optional:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2})?\d{16}$/
```

That uses a non-capturing group around the `[a-zA-Z]{2}` and makes the entire group optional via the `?` after it.

If the validation were *different* (say, maybe the version with the letters at the start only does `\d{14}`), you could use an alternation:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{14}|\d{16})$/
```

(Beware the gotcha: Without the non-capturing around around the alternation, the `^` would be part of the first alternative but not the second, and the `$` would be part of the second alternative, but not the first.)

But in your specific case, you don't need that.